# Is it possible to have duplicate action names and parameter list for post and get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

is it possible to have 2 actions with the same name and parameters but one's a post, the other a get? e.g `Delete(id)` and `[HttpPost]Delete(id)`...i get an error saying that this is not allowed...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible. Just use [ActionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) attribute on one action:

```
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            //...
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult Delete_Post(int id)
        {
            //...
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand why this was initially voted down since it's a very valid question. I've read that some people recommend you should pass in a random parameter or FormCollection, but that seems like overkill. This sounds like a better way to do it. Much appreciated!

Comment: just a question...why does mvc not allow 2 actions with the same signature? i'd think it's because the controller wouldn't know which action to call, but surely with the HttpPost this wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: This is actually not MVC related. By C# specification, signature of a method must be unique in a class in which it is declared. If you think about it, if there are no attributes, how would you distinguish them?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the error that it is not allowed is because C# itself gets confused.  While in MVC you can add attributes to specify whether a function is HttpGet or HttpPost, that doesn't help C# determine the difference between one or the other.  In order to have 2 functions with exactly the same name, the parameter list needs to be different.

As frennky pointed out, the ActionName attribute works in MVC because MVC uses aliases as part of the process for determining which action to call (along with attributes, but not parameters).

As a side note, it's probably best not to have a Delete action on a GET request.  You don't want a crawler or some other bot accidently hitting the wrong link :P