# MVC 6 Web Api Duplicate http Actions (Post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This seemed so simple to me but I'm missing the boat.

I have one controller that handles two different types of POST actions.

```
[HttpPost("")]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Category mdl)
{ ... snip... }


[HttpPost("")]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]SubCategory mdl)
{ ... snip... }
```

The only difference is the object parameter in the signature. Initially I thought this would suffice that MVC would be able to differentiate but it failed. When I have one or the other commented out the uncommented one works.
OK so then I tried this:

```
[HttpPost(Name = "UpdateCat")]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Category mdl)
{ ... snip... }


[HttpPost(Name = "UpdateSubCat")]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]SubCategory mdl)
{ ... snip... }
```

But this didn't make any difference either? So I started googling and came across this but it isn't quite what I'm after as these are different http actions sharing the same name.

[Is it possible to have duplicate action names and parameter list for post and get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198601/is-it-possible-to-have-duplicate-action-names-and-parameter-list-for-post-and-ge)

What am I misunderstanding about handling different post actions?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you cannot just rename one of the methods?

Comment: No..Guess I should clarify this is an academic venture for me. If I did rename how would it change the api url? Say I am currently posting to localhost/api/test  would it be localhost/api/test/renamedpostmethod?

Comment: Are the sub categories associated with a category in any way?

Comment: @Nkosi Yes the Categories are parents and the subcategories children. Id in Categories is a column in subcategories with FK relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have 2 POST methods in same web api controller, you may define a specific route pattern for the second POST method using the Route attribute.

```
public class CategoryController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Category mdl)
    { 
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mdl);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/api/products/SaveSubCat")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SubCategory  mdl)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mdl);
    }
}
```

Now your requests will be different

`api/products/` will hit the first action method and `api/producs/savesucat` will hit the second one.

I suggest you move your second action to a SubCategory controller and use it's default POST method.

Comment: Your theory is sound. Take note that based on the OP's `HttpPost(string)` attributes I believe the OP is referring to MVC6 and your answer relates to WebApi2.*.

Comment: @Shyju...you are right and right. I can change the route and achieve two post in a controller...but you are more spot on...it really should be in a separate controller. Thank You.